# How to sort the column header of a multi-index pivot table using lists

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort my pivot table columns based on lists that contain my preferred sorting. Example Below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['name1', 'name2', 'name1', 'name2', 'name2','name2'], 
                   'Block':['Block 1','Block 1', 'Block 10','Block 2','Block 2','Block 2'], 
                   'Week':['wk1','wk2','wk42','wk11','wk9','wk8'],
                   'Date':['01/15/2020','01/20/2020','11/29/2020','05/01/2020','04/20/2020','04/15/2020'],
                   'Events':['SIR','','','RSNA', '','CORE'],
                   'Rotation':['ABD','MAM','ER','UMH','PEDI','VIR']
                  })


df_summary = df.pivot_table(index=['Rotation'], columns=['Block','Week','Date','Events'], values='Name', aggfunc="count").fillna(0).astype(int)
```

which generates the following pivot table

[image: pivot]

The pivot table columns are not in preferred order. I would like to use the sorting of my lists:

```
blocks = ['Block 1','Block 2','Block 10']
weeks = ['wk1','wk2','wk8','wk9','wk11','wk42']
dates = ['01/15/2020','01/20/2020','04/15/2020','04/20/2020','05/01/2020','11/29/2020']
```

so i tried `.reindex` (see below) but keep getting an error - **TypeError: Expected tuple, got str**

```
df_summary = df_summary.reindex(columns=blocks)
```

or

```
df_summary = df_summary.reindex(columns=blocks,weeks,dates)
```

Can this be done using reindex with lists? Should i be trying to reindex with dictionaries? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple using `pd.crosstab` with `natsorted`

```
from natsort import natsorted
df.Block=pd.Categorical(df.Block,categories=natsorted(df.Block.unique()),ordered=True)
s=pd.crosstab(df.Rotation,[df.Block,df.Week,df.Date,df.Events]).sort_index(level=0,axis=1)
s
Out[305]: 
Block       Block 1               Block 2                         Block 10
Week            wk1        wk2       wk11        wk8        wk9       wk42
Date     01/15/2020 01/20/2020 05/01/2020 04/15/2020 04/20/2020 11/29/2020
Events          SIR                  RSNA       CORE                      
Rotation                                                                  
ABD               1          0          0          0          0          0
ER                0          0          0          0          0          1
MAM               0          1          0          0          0          0
PEDI              0          0          0          0          1          0
UMH               0          0          1          0          0          0
VIR               0          0          0          1          0          0
```

Comment: This doesnt appear to fix the sorting of my column headers. I'd like the sorting used in my lists

Answer (score 0):

This solution creates a `MultiIndex` object from your specified lists and then uses it as an argument to `DataFrame.reindex()`.  The *events* must also be considered because they are part of your original column-index.

```
blocks = 2*['Block 1'] + 3*['Block 2'] + ['Block 10']
weeks = ['wk1','wk2','wk8','wk9','wk11','wk42']
dates = ['01/15/2020','01/20/2020','04/15/2020','04/20/2020','05/01/2020','11/29/2020']
events = ['SIR','','CORE', '', 'RSNA', '']

midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
   arrays=[blocks, weeks, dates, events], 
   names=['Block', 'Week', 'Date', 'Event']
)

df_summary.reindex(columns=midx)

# returns the following:
Block       Block 1               Block 2                         Block 10
Week            wk1        wk2        wk8        wk9       wk11       wk42
Date     01/15/2020 01/20/2020 04/15/2020 04/20/2020 05/01/2020 11/29/2020
Event           SIR                  CORE                  RSNA           
Rotation                                                                  
ABD               1          0          0          0          0          0
ER                0          0          0          0          0          1
MAM               0          1          0          0          0          0
PEDI              0          0          0          1          0          0
UMH               0          0          0          0          1          0
VIR               0          0          1          0          0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this way more intuitiv and easier to implement:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]} {0[1]} {0[2]}'.format)
```

This just concatenates the (three) leveled header into one single header, no no need to import any other library.

Of course you have to adapt the map argument to address more or less columnns.